# countif skips some values out of nowhere

Tags: excel, string, count, numbers, countif

Hello Stack overflow folks.

I have encountered two questions one is about error and the other one is a pure question.

I have an excel table as below.
and tried to count the number of cells having a certain entity such as
tkn, udn, stuff like this (see the attached screen shot below)
[image]

I input the function like below.
[image]

however, it counted some entities correctly, but in case of "akn" entity, excel only counted one, while I could find more than five akn in the table by just hitting ctrl+f. 
why excel skips some and only counts one out of the table?

Comment: maybe your data has spaces or other non printable characters like: `"akn "`  You can try `=COUNTIFS($B$5:$S$135,"*" & V4 & "*")`

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth cleansing your data range by:

- Select entire range
- ctrl + H
- in find field: " "
- in replace with field: ""
- click replace all

It will remove all spaces from your data range.